# Images on android seem to stick while scrolling

Tags: android, jquery, css

**EDIT** it seems removing content that is generated dynamically with jquery fixes the problem, but it doesn't seem to be a specific piece of code. The function I removed to fix the problem on the home page is not on any other page and the problem persists. So this seems like a jQuery problem affecting my scroll?

I'm using androids stock browser galaxy s3 mini, and the images on my page seem to stick while I'm touch scrolling, when I let go they pop back into place. It looks horrible.

What's causing the sticking of images?

I'm not sure where to start but here's a link to my site [http://lartmagazine.co.uk](http://lartmagazine.co.uk/)

If you look at it on the stock android browser the images all seem to stick.

Would it be something to do with my container css?

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#scroller {
  position: absolute;
  overflow:scroll;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:40px;
  bottom:0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
  -o-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

**EDIT:** so for instance if I comment out this masonry function the scrolling bug no longer happens:

```
function masonry_shiz(){
        $('#gal1').masonry({
            singleMode: true,
            "gutter": 0,
            isFitWidth: true,
            isAnimated: true
        }).imagesLoaded(function() {
            $('#gal1').masonry('reloadItems');
        });
        $(window).load(function() {
            $(".masonry-brick").each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay((i + 1) * 50).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }masonry_shiz();
```

Comment: To clarify, what are you adding with jQuery? Can you post that in the question?